# CGContextSetShadow produces no results

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm using this code in my UIView subclass to draw a circle with a gradient fill:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetShadow (context, CGSizeMake(4,4), 5);
    CGContextBeginPath (context);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, 38, 38));
    CGContextClosePath (context);
    CGContextClip (context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(self.bounds)), CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.bounds)), 0);
}
```

The circle and the gradient draw fine, but I see no shadow. I'm not sure why its not working, because I used the same CGContextSetShadow function in a different view subclass and it worked fine.

**NOTE:** In the above code, "gradient" is an ivar that was defined previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A gradient draw doesn't count as a fill; only fills and strokes get shadows. (You may want to [report this as a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).)

As a workaround, *fill* the path (with solid black), then turn off the shadow, then draw the gradient.

Comment: Did you mean turn on or turn off the shadow? I'm not quite getting the train of thought.

Comment: Turn off. Fill with it on, then turn it off and draw the gradient with it off.