# How to draw a drop shadow AND gradient with quartz2d?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I've a custom shape drawing using coregraphics and i want to add a drop shadow and a gradient to it also. I've been trying and searching a lot of informations on how to combine and do this, but i can't get it to work. I'm able to draw only one either.
Anyone doing this already or know how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263273/cgcontextsetshadow-produces-no-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz only applies shadows to fills and strokes. Drawing a gradient does not count as a fill.

Fill with a solid color (to draw the shadow), then draw the gradient in the same area.

Comment: so just to clarify...

1. draw a shape with solid color fill
2. save the state
3. draw the shadow
4. restore the state
5. draw the same shape as point 1 but with the gradient

is this correct? so i need to draw the shape 3 times right?

Comment: There is no way to “draw the shadow”. Quartz draws the shadow for you when you fill or stroke. So, set the shadow, then fill (with a solid color) the shape, then draw the gradient over it.

Comment: Looks like you're right Peter, but I think it might be an oversight, albeit a difficult one to fix.  Images and text draw shadows, for example, as do transparency layers and CGLayers.  I cannot think of any non-shading based drawing that _doesn't_ produce a shadow.  The header just says "After a shadow is specified, all objects drawn subsequently will be shadowed."